# How to customize title of Primefaces Schedule

Tags: primefaces, internationalization

I am developping a french application, using Primefaces (6.2) Schedule component. I want to display the day date according to the french convention (ie : `dd mm yyyy` rather than `mm dd, yyyy`) in the schedule's title.

It seems that I need to configure / override the fullCalendar `titleFormat` option, but I can't configure it using the Primefaces taglib (`p:schedule)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Fullcalendar titleFormat documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/titleFormat) :

You need to do the following :

```
titleFormat = {
    month : "MMMM YYYY",
    week : "D MMMM YYYY",
    day :"DDDD D MMMM YYYY"
};
```

Primefaces Schedule does not have any attribute to set this option, but you can give Primefaces a Javascript `extender` function to customize the fullCalendar options (cf : [PrimeFaces PDF User Guide](https://www.primefaces.org/docs/guide/primefaces_user_guide_6_2.pdf)).

This will gives you the following XHTML code :

```
<p:schedule id="mySchedule" ... extender="titleFormatExtender" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function titleFormatExtender(){
        this.cfg.titleFormat={
            month : "MMMM YYYY",
            week : "D MMMM YYYY",
            day : "dddd D MMMM YYYY"
        };
    }
</script>
```